# Velocity loop through JSON

Tags: velocity, marketo

I am using Velocity to try and loop through some JSON data I have in a field in Marketo. I have used [the tutorial here](http://blog.teknkl.com/marketo-json-fields-in-velocity/) to change the JSON into a Velocity Map but have an issue trying to loop through the data which is now a map.

```
#set( $items = ${abandonedBasket_cList} )

###if( $items.get(7).basketJSON.isEmpty() )
###set( $items.get(7).basketJSON = '[]' )
###end

#foreach ($item in $items)
    #if( $foreach.last )
        #set( $lastitem = $item.basketJSON )
    #end 
#end

#set( $ClientReferrals = '#set( $ClientReferrals = ' + $lastitem + ' ) ' )
#evaluate( $ClientReferrals )


${ClientReferrals[0].itemDesc}       ## outputs "Season Pass Holders"
<br>
${ClientReferrals[1].customerID}     ## outputs "jill@example2.com"
<br>
```

I have managed output values from the "map" when using a specific static index like in the example.

The bit I am stuck on is trying to get it to loop through each object using the foreach tool in Velocity as I don't know how to iterate the [index] key as part of the loop.

### Update

I have tried to use the code suggested but there is nothing displaying.

```
#foreach($key in $ClientReferrals.keySet())
   #set($item = $ClientReferrals[$key])
   $item.itemDesc
   ${item.itemDesc}
   $item
   ${item}
#end
```

If I output what $ClientReferrals looks like this is what I get. Does this look like a Hashmap to you?

```
[{id=29071940, itemDesc=1.33ct AA Tanzanite 9K Gold Earrings, itemImage=https://cdn.gemporia.com/images/products/300/NJPS19.jpg, itemQuantity=1, itemPrice=£151.00, customerID=1132399, basketURL=https://secure.gemporia.com/basket.aspx, isAuction=false, stock=10, dateAdded=2017-02-15}, {id=29071946, itemDesc=Size J to K AA Tanzanite & White Zircon 9K Gold Ring ATGW 1.08cts, itemImage=https://cdn.gemporia.com/images/products/300/OZVJ80.5.jpg, itemQuantity=1, itemPrice=£89.99, customerID=1132399, basketURL=https://secure.gemporia.com/basket.aspx, isAuction=true, stock=1, dateAdded=2017-02-15}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `$ClientReferrals` is a map, then you can do:

```
#foreach($key in $ClientReferrals.keySet())
   #set($item = $ClientReferrals[$key])
   ...
#end
```

Items won't be sorted by key for an HashMap, they will for a TreeMap.

By the way, to get the last item of an array, you can do:

```
#set($last_index = $items.size() - 1)
#set($last = $items[$last_index])
```

Comment: Updated my comment as I can't get it to work with the code suggested. Any idea? :)

Comment: Yes: it looks like $ClientReferrals is not a map but an array of maps, whereas I thought you had a map id->item. Maps appear like `{...}` and arrays like `[...]`.

Comment: I really don't see why you can't do `#foreach($item in $ClientReferrals)`.

Comment: I don't know why it did not work before (maybe a typo on my part) but what you have suggested works perfectly!